# Turning left and right in reverse

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I'm holding "S" key, the car turns correctly, but if I relase it the car is turning in wrong direction.
Here is my code:

```cs
public class CarDrive : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float moveInput;
    [SerializeField] private float turnInput;

    public float fwdSpeed;
    public float revSpeed;
    public float turnSpeed;

    Vector3 localVel;

    public Rigidbody sphereRB;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        sphereRB.transform.parent = null;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        moveInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        turnInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

        moveInput *= fwdSpeed > 0 ? fwdSpeed : revSpeed;

        transform.position = sphereRB.transform.position;

        var localVelocity = transform.InverseTransformDirection(sphereRB.velocity);
        float newRotation = turnInput * turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

        if(localVelocity.z < 0){
            newRotation *= -1;
        }

        if(sphereRB.velocity.magnitude != 0){
            transform.Rotate(0, newRotation, 0, Space.World);
        }

        Debug.Log(localVel);
    }

    private void FixedUpdate() {
        sphereRB.AddForce(transform.forward * moveInput, ForceMode.Acceleration);
    }
}
```

I tried to fix it, by adding local velocity variable, but it doesn't help, because when the car is turning more than 90 degrees, the velocity is negative.

Comment: does letting go of the `S` automatically mean your forward `velocity` is immediately `0` ...?

Answer (score 0):

Test for the key instead

```cs
moveInput *= Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) ? fwdSpeed : revSpeed;
```

or

```cs
moveInput *= Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) ? revSpeed : fwdSpeed;
```